# Google Chrome not respecting value of key in manifest.json?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension that uses [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging). Part of the requirements for developing such an extension is that the extension's ID does not change.

[The documentation for the `key` entry in `manifest.json`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/key) states the following:

> This value can be used to control the unique ID of an extension, app, or theme when it is loaded during development.

Therefore, I added the key to `manifest.json` as follows:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "key": "cljjpoinofmbdnbnpebolibochlfenag",
    ...
}
```

I then visited `chrome://extensions` and clicked "Load unpacked extension..." to browse to the directory containing the extension's code. However, the ID assigned does not match the one that I specified:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the wording is a bit misleading in this sentence:

> "This value can be used to control the unique ID of an extension, app, or theme when it is loaded during development."

Although the value *controls* the unique ID, it is not the unique ID itself. To find the correct value of the key, you will need to:

- Install the extension from the Chrome Web Store
- Open your user profile directory and examine:

  ```
    Extensions/[id]/[version]/manifest.json
  ```
- Copy the value for `key` from the file

After doing this, the unpacked extension should now be assigned the correct ID.